# Android studio не видит файлы анимации

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

Проблема,собственно,представлена на скриншоте. Файл myanim.xml есть в, но студия его не видит.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не пробовали "File>>Invalidate Caches\Restart>>Invalidate and Restart"?

Comment: Помогло,спасибо